# What use is a truncated coredump?

Tags: linux, gdb, posix, x86-64, coredump

`ulimit -c` can be used to set `RLIMIT_CORE`, and limit the maximum size of a coredump a process may generate. Any larger coredump will be truncated to this size.

Can anything useful be done with such a truncated coredump? Perhaps on a platform other than Linux x86-64, or with a debugger other than GDB?

If not, why does POSIX [specify this behavior](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/getrlimit.html), rather than, say, truncating a coredump to zero bytes if `RLIMIT_CORE` is exceeded?

Comment: I wasn't sure whether to post this here or on [unix.se]. I'd be happy to repost it there, if that's more appropriate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can anything useful be done with such a truncated coredump?

Yes, *lots* of things.

The truncated core dump will usually contain the stack segments, so the commands `where` and `thread apply all where` will usually work. Often that's all one needs from a core. Commands to examine local variables and globals will likely work as well.

Commands to examine heap-allocated variables may work for some variables, but not necessarily for others. Still, this is *much* better than nothing.